# Format double as integer when no decimal places

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I am trying to write a java function that will take a double as it's input, and return the double formatted as a string to the minimum number of decimal places required.

E.g.

Input:Result

50.000 : 50

12.500 : 12.5

74.125 : 74.125

Is there a suitable string format that I can use, or do I need to test the last character of the string to see if it's a 0? This would work, I'm sure, but seems a little agricultural.

I know there are a lot of questions on here about the reverse, and I apologise if this is a duplicate question - I did try to search!

Comment: it is indeed a duplicate of that question. Perfect answer.

Comment: @user2496329 hope you are not talking about accepted one if you can have values larger than max int/long

Comment: Shouldn't do - writing this for a workout-logging type program,(where I'm storing the weight as a double - correct me if this is wrong) so unless people start smashing out some *very* big records, I should be okay!